# docusaurus error: Bad Docusaurus plugin value plugins[0]

Tags: reactjs, docusaurus

I tried to run my docusaurus application that worked o.k before and I have an error without changing anything...

This is the error I get:

```
E:\ngDocs>npm run start

> ngdocs@0.0.0 start
> docusaurus start

[INFO] Starting the development server...
[ERROR] Error:  => Bad Docusaurus plugin value plugins[0].
Example valid plugin config:
{
  plugins: [
    ["@docusaurus/plugin-content-docs",options],
    "./myPlugin",
    ["./myPlugin",{someOption: 42}],
    function myPlugin() { },
    [function myPlugin() { },options]
  ],
};


    at validateConfig (E:\ngDocs\node_modules\@docusaurus\core\lib\server\configValidation.js:228:15)
    at loadSiteConfig (E:\ngDocs\node_modules\@docusaurus\core\lib\server\config.js:40:62)
    at async loadContext (E:\ngDocs\node_modules\@docusaurus\core\lib\server\index.js:31:63)
    at async load (E:\ngDocs\node_modules\@docusaurus\core\lib\server\index.js:74:21)
    at async Command.start (E:\ngDocs\node_modules\@docusaurus\core\lib\commands\start.js:44:19)
[INFO] Docusaurus version: 2.4.0
Node version: v16.17.0
```

I have no idea what to do. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the version of Docusaurus.
This issue may arise when the installed package versions are newer than @docusaurus/core.
I encountered the same problem just now and managed to resolve it.